# java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.GDSFactoryPlugin: Error reading configuration file from Java Stored Procedure in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, firebird, jaybird, loadjava

I loaded with loadjava tool Jaybird-3.0.9-JDK_1.8 JDBC driver and my java class to Oracle database. All classes were resolved. When I run Java Stored Procedure from Oracle first time got

> error ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.GDSFactoryPlugin: Error reading configuration file

when the java application was creating connection.

The next calls with the same Oracle connection lead to

> ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

After reconnect I get ServiceConfigurationError exception again.
The same code works fine from java. Any good idea? Many thanks

Comment: Please provide the full exception stacktraces.

Comment: Unfornunately, I see in sqldevelper only ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.GDSFactoryPlugin: Error reading configuration file
ORA-06512: at "C##AGRO_9.POMPA_PKG", line 71
ORA-06512: at "C##AGRO_9.POMPA_PKG", line 74
ORA-06512: at "C##AGRO_9.POMPA_PKG", line 68
29532. 00000 -  "Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: %s"
*Cause:    A Java exception or error was signaled and could not be
           resolved by the Java code.
*Action:   Modify Java code, if this behavior is not intended.

Comment: Will try to write exception stacktrace to database, good idea

Comment: In any case, the first error seems to indicate that whatever loadjava does, it doesn't correctly store the files in `META-INF/services`, or the way Oracle classloader works disallows loading those files, as a result, Jaybird can't configure some of its parts. Normally, this would cause a fallback to a built-in list, but it looks like this ServiceConfigurationError is thrown where Jaybird doesn't expect it, and thus it isn't caught. The stacktrace would help me identify the cause and where it is thrown.

Comment: For the moment I can't caught it, but still work on it. Many thanks, will continue

Comment: In any case, I have a best guess at the cause, and a fix will be available in the next version of Jaybird, see http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC-636

Answer (score 0):

Jaybird loads some of its components as plugins through `java.util.ServiceLoader`, and if that doesn't work, it will fallback to a fixed list of plugins. Unfortunately, in this case a `ServiceConfigurationError` was thrown where Jaybird didn't expect it, and thus this error wasn't handled and as a result, the loading of the class `GDSFactory` was terminated (which causes the subsequent `NoClassDefFoundError`).

Based on your question, I don't know exactly what this failure is, but at a guess either loadjava or the Oracle classloader seems to have corrupted the service definition file (`META-INF/services/org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.GDSFactoryPlugin`), or otherwise causes an exception when it is read.

I have created bug [JDBC-636](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC-636), to handle this exception in Jaybird 3.0.10, 4.0.2, and in the upcoming Jaybird 5.

Jaybird 3.0.10 and 4.0.2 have been released, so use those versions instead of the snapshots below.

<s>As long as Jaybird 3.0.10 and 4.0.2 have not been released, you can try the 3.0.10-SNAPSHOT or 4.0.2.java8-SNAPSHOT from the Sonatype snapshot repository (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots) using Maven or Gradle. Or you can download the jar directly from the snapshot repository (NOTE: these links will break when newer snapshots have been deployed):</s>

- <s>[3.0.10-SNAPSHOT](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/firebirdsql/jdbc/jaybird-jdk18/3.0.10-SNAPSHOT/jaybird-jdk18-3.0.10-20201219.134254-1.jar) (or find the latest in https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/firebirdsql/jdbc/jaybird-jdk18/3.0.10-SNAPSHOT/)</s>
- <s>[4.0.2.java8-SNAPSHOT](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/firebirdsql/jdbc/jaybird/4.0.2.java8-SNAPSHOT/jaybird-4.0.2.java8-20201219.135643-1.jar) (or find the latest in https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/firebirdsql/jdbc/jaybird/4.0.2.java8-SNAPSHOT/)</s>

Comment: Mark, many thanks for your assist. With 3.0.10 I got a stacktraces

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: No message for code 335544421 found. [SQLState:HY000, ISC error code:335544421]
 at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.FbExceptionBuilder$Type$1.createSQLException(FbExceptionBuilder.java:532)
 at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.FbExceptionBuilder.toFlatSQLException(FbExceptionBuilder.java:302)
 at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.WireConnection.identify(WireConnection.java:326)
 at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.FbWireDatabaseFactory.performConnect(FbWireDatabaseFactory.java:51)
 at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.FbWireDatabaseFactory.connect(FbWireDatabaseFactory.java:39)

Comment: at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.FbWireDatabaseFactory.connect(FbWireDatabaseFactory.java:32)
 at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBManagedConnection.<init>(FBManagedConnection.java:142)
 at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(FBManagedConnectionFactory.java:558)
 at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBStandAloneConnectionManager.allocateConnection(FBStandAloneConnectionManager.java:65)
 at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDataSource.getConnection(FBDataSource.java:124)
 at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver.connect(FBDriver.java:143)

Comment: next part maybe not important  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java)
 at org.wgsoftpro.ads.ADSConnect.getConnection(ADSConnect.java:137)
 at org.wgsoftpro.ads.ADSConnect.getConnection2Source(ADSConnect.java:252)
 at org.wgsoftpro.ads.ADSConnect.readResultSet(ADSConnect.java:68)
 ...
 at org.wgsoftpro.ads.ADSConnect.getResultSetbyStringID(ADSConnect.java:43)
Caused by: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLExceptionInfo: No message for code 335544421 found.

Comment: @AltiyZemlytskiy That stacktrace is an entirely different problem, but also indicates that there is definitely a problem loading resources from the classpath in your setup. Error code 335544421 is  "connection rejected by remote interface", see [connection rejected by remote interface (335544421)](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/faq.html#connection-rejected-by-remote-interface-335544421) in the Jaybird FAQ. If that doesn't help, consider asking a new question here, or on the [firebird-java Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-java).

Comment: Checked  error code 335544421 from FAQ, username and login are not null, nothing is mentioned in firebird.log, WireCrypt = enabled infirebird.conf, paragraph 3.4.5 - I think is not my case. Looks like I need your help again, what else shall I check? Many thanks

Comment: @AltiyZemlytskiy Please ask on the firebird-java Google Group. Comments on an answer are not a good venue for troubleshooting.

Comment: @AltiyZemlytskiy However, I'm guessing that your deployment of Jaybird is so corrupted, that Jaybird can't read resources (as indicated by the fact that you don't have error messages, just error codes), which means that Jaybird also can't read some files that define what connection properties and other things exist (and what their type is).